# JavaScript bitwise NOT ~ doesn't produce same result

Tags: javascript, bit, bitwise-not

I am attempting to invert the binary digits of a base-10 value using JavaScript, according to this **[W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp)**, JavaScript's ***Bitwise NOT*** operator *(i.e. `~`)* should do just that.

In an example they show `~5` resulting in a value of `10`, but when I attempt to execute the simple program **...**

```
console.log(~5);
```

**...** the RTE logs `-6`, not `10`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `~5` is in fact `-6`. You're getting the correct answer.

Comment: The example you are referring to uses 4-bit unsigned numbers. In the real world using 32-bit or 64-bit *signed* numbers, `~5` is `-6`, as you can see from the other examples on the same page. However, since the page doesn't mention it is working with 4-bit unsigned numbers it is misleading. Try to find a better tutorial, there are plenty of questions on [so] that prove that w3schools is a source of low-quality information.

Comment: I love that there's even a big yellow box that says, "Because of this ~ 5 returns 10."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll down a bit at the website ([https://www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp)), you find this information (as axiac has already written):

> The examples above uses 4 bits unsigned binary numbers. Because of
>   this ~ 5 returns 10.
>
> Since **JavaScript uses 32 bits signed integers**, it will not return 10.
>   It will return -6.
>
> 00000000000000000000000000000101 (5)
>
> 11111111111111111111111111111010 (~5 = -6)
>
> A signed integer uses the leftmost bit as the minus sign.

So you didn’t do anything wrong.

```js
var x = 5;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=~5;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```